# Compare 2 Dimensional int array with string array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, int

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main(){

int numstud=0, numcorrect, i, j, grid[20][5]={0}, x;
string key, id, responses;
ifstream keyfin, studfin;
keyfin.open("answers.dat");
studfin.open("tests.dat");

keyfin >> key;
studfin >> id >> responses;

cout << setw(5) << "Student-Id's" << setw(20) << "# Correct" << endl << endl;

while(!studfin.eof())
{
    numstud++;
    numcorrect=0;
    for(i=0; i<20; i++){

        if(responses[i] == key[i])
        {
            numcorrect++;
        }
        if(responses[i] == 'A')
            grid[i][0]++;
        else if(responses[i] == 'B')
            grid[i][1]++;
        else if(responses[i] == 'C')
            grid[i][2]++;
        else if(responses[i] == 'D')
            grid[i][3]++;
        else 
            grid[i][4]++;
        }

    cout << id << setw(20) <<numcorrect << endl;
    studfin >> id >> responses;






}


    cout << endl << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "Questions" << setw(16) << "A" << setw(5) << "B" << setw(5) << "C" << setw(5) << "D" << setw(5) << "E" << endl; 

    for(j=0; j<20; j++){


        cout << endl << setw(5) << j+1 << setw(20);

        for(i=0; i<5; i++)

        if(grid[i] == key[i])
            cout << grid[j][i] << "*" << setw(5);
        else
            cout << grid[j][i] << " " << setw(5);

    }
    cout << endl;
    system("Pause"); 

}
```

This is a very simple question and hopefully a very simple answer, I need to compare grid[i] to key[i] so I can check to format that differently depending on whether it is == or !=

My problem is that grid is an int and key is a string.  How would you go about comparing these two for an `if` `else` operand?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `string` to an `int` with `std::stoi()`:

```
if(grid[i] == stoi(key[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`grid` is a 2D array, so `if(grid[i] == key[i])` is wrong. Change to `if(grid[j][i] == (key[i]) - '0')`.

`grid[i]` meaning the address of `grid[i][0] (&grid[i][0]`, so compare them is not reasonable.

`key[i]` is a char type, `atoi` need parameter as `const char *`, so use `atoi` is **incorrect**. compare between `char` and `int` via ascii value is the most efficient way. `key[i] - '0'` cast a number from `char` to `int` value.

Comment: when I do atoi(key[i])) it says type of char is incompatible with const char